# General equation of midpoint of chord of hyperbola

Tags: conic-sections

$ \frac{x^2}{a^2}+ \frac{y^2}{b^2} =1$

is

$ \frac{xx'} {a^2} + \frac{yy'} {b^2} = \frac{x'^2}{a^2}+ \frac{y'^2}{b^2}$

where (x',y') are coordinates of midpoint

This is apparently true for all conics. Where is this coming from?

Comment: (You meant to write ellipse?) In Joachimsthal's notation this is equivalent to $s_1=s_{11}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this book](https://books.google.no/books?id=wTw8AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA227&lpg=PA227&dq=joachimsthal+chord&source=bl&ots=cpa7tJoy4u&sig=QztwylpY_SqSoIvtLMzWLUfJu6E&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjjqLuBktzXAhUKbVAKHaHgBagQ6AEINDAD#v=onepage&q=joachimsthal%20chord&f=false). For more on Joachimsthal's notation see [this page](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Generalization/JoachimsthalsNotations.shtml).

> Find the equation of the chord of $s=0$ whose midpoint is $P_1$.

[image: chord]

Let $AA'$ be the chord and if possible let it meet the polar of $P_1$ in $P_2$. Then $AP_1=P_1A'$, $$AP_2=-P_2A'=A'P_2,$$ which is absurd. Therefore the chord cannot meet the polar of $P_1$. Hence it is parallel to the polar and has equation $s_1=k$. But it passes through $P_1$.

$\therefore$ $s_{11}=k$. Hence the chord is $$s_1=s_{11}.$$

Comment: I don't get it : ( how is AP2 = - P2A'?

Comment: @Vrisk: Use that the polar are the points $P_2$ s.t. the cross-ratio $(P_1AP_2A')=-1$.

Comment: Could u please explain more on how do you prove that the polar of the midpoint is parallel to the chord, rest I understood ?

Comment: @ss1729 See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_harmonic_conjugate.