# Equation of the chord of the hyperbola $x^2-y^2=9$ which is bisected at $(5,-3)$

Tags: conic-sections

> Find the equation of the chord of the hyperbola $x^2-y^2=9$ which is bisected at $(5,-3)$

This is solved in my reference as:
$$
T=S_1\implies x(5)-y(-3)-9=5^2-(-3)^2-9\\
5x+3y-16=0
$$
What is the logic behind such a substitution, $T=S_1$ ?

And how can I solve the problem without making this shortcut ?

Comment: What are $T$ and $S_1$?

Comment: I imagine $T\equiv xx_1-yy_1-9$ and $S_1\equiv x_1^2-y_1^2-9$ where $(x_1,y_1)$ is the relevant point on the $x-y$ plane.

Comment: As for the reasoning behind it, perhaps homogeneization.

Comment: https://archive.org/details/elementsofcoordi00lone

Comment: It's about pole and polar, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola#Pole-polar_relation_for_a_hyperbola

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2537837/620957). It's about ellipses, but i think it's the same proof. It uses the polar.

Comment: @Milten Thanks, but I don't actually understnad how the polar of the midpoint is parallel to the chord ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
P(\sec a,\tan a)\quad;\quad Q(\sec b,\tan b)\\
(5,-3)=(\frac{\sec a+\sec b}{2},\frac{\tan a+\tan b}{2})=(\frac{1}{2}\frac{\cos a+\cos b}{\cos a\cos b},\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sin a\cos b+\cos a\sin b}{\cos a\cos b})\\
=(\frac{2\cos\frac{a+b}{2}\cos\frac{a-b}{2}}{2\cos a\cos b},\frac{2\sin\frac{a+b}{2}\cos\frac{a+b}{2}}{2\cos a\cos b})\\
m=\frac{\tan b-\tan a}{\sec b-\sec a}=\frac{\sin(a-b)}{\cos a-\cos b}=\frac{2\sin\frac{a-b}{2}\cos\frac{a-b}{2}}{2\sin\frac{a-b}{2}\sin\frac{a+b}{2}}=\frac{\cos\frac{a-b}{2}}{\sin\frac{a+b}{2}}\\
y+3=\frac{\cos\frac{a-b}{2}}{\sin\frac{a+b}{2}}(x-5)=\frac{-5}{3}(x-5)\\
\implies 3y+9=-5x+25\implies5x+3y=16
$$

Answer (score 0):

It is $y=-\frac53x+\frac{16}3$.

Details: Let the equation be $y=ax+b$. It passes through $(5,-3)$ and crosses the hyperbola at two points:
$$\begin{cases}-3=5a+b \\ x^2-(ax+b)^2=9\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases}b=-3-5a\\ (1-a^2)x^2+2a(3+5a)x-(3+5a)^2-9=0\end{cases} \Rightarrow \\
x_{1,2}=\frac{-a(3+5a)\pm \sqrt{a^2(3+5a)^2+(1-a^2)((3+5a)^2+9)}}{1-a^2}$$
From the midpoint:
$$\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}=5 \Rightarrow \frac{-a(3+5a)}{1-a^2}=5 \Rightarrow a=-\frac53,b=\frac{16}{3}.$$
Reference: Desmos [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gjc8khhzye).